# Formatting title Page

Tags: titles

I created a title page, But the text is not in center of the page and student name and details of professor is not in the bottom of the corner! How I can solve this issue?

The link is here https://www.overleaf.com/7384823717vntcjyjfyxnm

Comment: please see the answer if it meets the rwquirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this how you want it?

I have increased `\vspace` in the `Portada.tex` to shift the names down

For the centering there was a n empty line after the title `Academic Task 2` I have deleted that so the horizontal line underneath the heading gets shifted upward

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\vspace{8cm}%opcional<---------------------increase to create more vertical space 
\begin{tabular}{l}
```

[image]